# Code ignoring if statements - C++

Tags: c++

I've been working on a password generator for my College coursework, and one of the parts to this involves creating 'Complex' passwords, which are passwords which are nothing more than strings of random characters, and the user should be able to specify what types of characters are used. However, the set of if statements which control if a function is used don't activate based on the values within uppertrue numbertrue and lowertrue, they all act as if the statement returns true, and so the function is always run. 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
int upper(), lower(), number(), symbol();   //initializing functions to be    used to generate the ascii code
int clength = 15;
int pass[30];  
int uppertrue = 0, numbertrue = 1, symboltrue = 0;
int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));                                                        //seed random generator
    int i = 0;                                                              //counter
    int which = 0;
    do
    {
        which = rand() % 4 + 1;     //randomly decides which type of character will be shown - probablity is unweighted for complex module
        if (which == 1)
        {
            pass[i] = lower();      //inserts the code returned  by the function into the array
            i++;
        }
        else if ((uppertrue == 1) && (which == 2))
        {
            pass[i] = upper();
            i++;
        }
        else if (numbertrue == 1 && which == 3)
        {
            pass[i] = number();
            i++;
        }
        else if (symboltrue == 1 && which == 4)
        {
            pass[i] = symbol();
            i++;
        }
    }while (i!=(clength+1));        //terminates loop when the array is complete
    std::string strpass;
    int x=0;
    do
    {
        char tempchar;
        tempchar = pass[x];
        std::cout << tempchar;
        x++;
    }while (x!=15);
    return 0;
}

int upper()     //creates random number between the range of ascii characters that results in caps
{
    return rand() % 65 + 26;

}

int number()    //same as upper but for numbers
{
    return rand() % 48 + 9;
}

int lower()     //same as upper but for lower case
{
    return rand() % 122 + 26;
}

int symbol()    //same as upper but for symbols (currently only supporting a few characters
{
    return rand() % 63 + 6;
}
```

if anyone can point me in the correct direction it would be much appreciated, it seems like it's a logical error but I can't see anything logically wrong with it. Is it perhaps to do with some sort of quirk with C++? (bearing in mind I was taught C and this is the first thing I've done in C++)
Many thanks
(A comment said to remove the part where i'd usually enter the values for uppertrue etc so i've hardcoded the values to show the problem instead)

Comment: Please reduce the problem a little bit. For starters, get rid of the `std::cin` calls and replace them with hard-coded input to demonstrate the problem as concisely as possible. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This isn't the problem you're asking about, but you need to do `rand() % 26 + 65` and `rand() % 26 + 97` (not 122). You can make this more readable with something like `rand() % ('Z' - 'A' + 1) + 'A'` and `rand() % ('z' - 'a' + 1) + 'a'`

Comment: Aside from the (incorrect) magic numbers, the code for `lower()`, `upper()`, `number()`, and `symbol()` is not portable. `number()` is easy to implement portably: `return rand() % 10 + '0';`. The others should be implemented with an array of `char`: `char lc[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";` and then `return lc[rand() % 26];`.

Comment: I think you broke the question with your code edit. Now `uppertrue`, `numbertrue` and `symboltrue` are never true, and the whole code is just confusing because of that... If they are always `false`, then just remove them and the code which can now be never executed. Or if that code is the point of the question, edit it so that they can be true.

Comment: What do you mean by "Entering a 1 when asked at the start"? You've removed the part of the program that asks for input.

Comment: When you have a variable like `uppertrue`, you should declare it as `bool` and just use `if (uppertrue)`. It's non-idiomatic to explicitly compare with `1`.

Comment: You haven't actually told us what the problem is. "Isn't working" can mean a lot of things. With your selection of uppertrue, numbertrue, and symboltrue only half the if statements can ever be true.

Comment: When I said you should remove the `std::cin`s, I was referring to the fact the mechanics of reading user input from a text stream are certainly not related to the problem. Not to mention that it makes it harder for people to help you, because nobody wants to guess what kind of input you're having problems with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
int lower()     // same as upper but for lower case
{
    return rand() % 122 + 26;
}
```

It will produce random number in range 26 ... 147. Which is something completely different than range for lower case characters. You want this:

```
    return rand() % ('z' - 'a' + 1) + 'a';
```

You should fix the other functions in similar manner.

Note to those who worry about their code being able to run on, for example, mainframes using EBCDIC character encoding: This assumes that a..z have continuous character codes.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I was looking in the completely wrong place trying to find the fix

Comment: Apologies for initially downvoting this. You do disclaim the *encoding* adequately and so long as the OP is aware of the portability constraints, this is an excellent answer.

Answer (score 1):

The *specific* problem is that you have bugs in the functions that return, at random, the various characters.

The C++ standard is intentionally vague as to the numeric values that it associates with characters. The precise mapping is down to the *implementation* and the scheme is called the *encoding*.

Whilst ASCII encoding is common, it's by no means universal and so in order to achieve *portability* it's best not to make assumptions about your platform unless you really need to.

So, you really ought to recast `lower` on the lines:

```
char lower
{
    const char* s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    return s[rand() % 26];
}
```

which is truly portable. I've also taken the liberty of changing your function return type.

You ought to do similar for `upper`. Your `symbols` function will drop out similarly.

I'd be tempted to adopt the same approach for `number` too but here the C++ standard *does* say something about the digits: the *encoding* **must** arrange the characters `0` to `9` to be in a contiguous block and in that order, so the statement

`return rand() % ('9' - '0' + 1) + '0';`

*is* portable. As a final remark, you *could* use `static char[] s = "abc...z";` and `(sizeof(s) - 1)` in place of the hardcoded 26. This is a quite advanced technique and not obvious to a beginner but do research it as your programming skills develop.

Comment: This approach is the only sensible one for the `symbol()` function, especially.